# Как в WPF получить доступ к data item из ListView.Resources?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ...>
          <ListView.Resources>
            <ContextMenu x:Key="ItemContextMenu">
              <MenuItem 
    Header="{Binding Path=Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
AncestorType=???}" IsEnabled="False"/>
              <MenuItem Header="Открыть в браузере"/>
             </ContextMenu>
           </ListView.Resources>
```

`Title` - это свойство, именно `data item`, а не `ListViewItem`.

Что должно быть на месте?

Знаю, что обойтись можно (нужно) и без этого, задав `ContextMenu` контейнеру в `DataTemplate`, но в данном случае так удобнее.

Comment: В вашем случае - никак. Создавайте шаблон ItemTemplate и в его родительском контейнере добавляйте ресурс

Comment: @Андрей надо именно так сделать, как в вопросе

Comment: ОК, подробнее опишите тогда. У вас есть некая коллекция объектов, которую вы устанавливаете как источник элементов для `ListView`, так? И у этих объектов (которые в коллекции) есть свойство `Title`, так?

Comment: А зачем вам ContextMenu в ресурсах? Вы ведь не собираетесь вставлять его оттуда в несколько мест, правда? И да, DataTemplate — хорошее решение.

Comment: @Андрей Да, все так.

Comment: @VladD если кратко - DataTemplate может меняться. а ContextMenu должно меняться отдельно. свой юзерконтрол пишу, состоящий из ListView и еще кое-чего. контрол не для конкретной задачи, как пишут обычно, а типа универсальный и должен отвечать сразу многим задачам (которых в WPF не перечесть), поэтому и нужна гибкость. возможно, для DataTemplate тоже будет возможность задать ContextMenu, но это не исключает первого.

Comment: @koshkashoshka: Ну положите ContextMenu в стиль тогда. А к `Title` **какого** объекта вы хотите привязаться?

Comment: @VladD Я число 3 считаю несчастливым. Вот когда еще один придет и спросит - тогда отвечу 4-ый раз, какого.

Comment: @koshkashoshka: Давайте я спрошу прямщас ещё раз, неохота заводить клон для этого.

Comment: @VladD того, которых ObservableCollection, привязанная к ItemsSource. т.е. модели. а не ListViewItem, не Window и не что-то еще.